# default values in input fields getting past validation on submission

Tags: jquery, validation

I wrote a small validation script (partially as an exercise in learning) but I can't figure out how to make it detect default values in the input fields.  It seems like I need to store the default value in a variable and then add another OR in there to check if the current value matches that default value but I can't quite figure out how to do that.  I can't put the variable inside the function executed on the click because then it takes the value at that point and uses that.  Any help would be appreciated.  I thought about just using "placeholder" but I wanted to make it work in IE.  thanks in advance.

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
var ret_val = true;
var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
$('.required').each(function(){
if($(this).val().length === 0 || $(this).find("option:selected").val() == "none") 
{
    $('#errormessage').removeClass('requiredmessage');
    ret_val = false;
    $(this).addClass('warning');
}
else if($(this).val().length != 0)
{
    $(this).removeClass('warning');
}
});
if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal))
{
    $('#emailerrormessage').removeClass('requiredmessage');
    $('#email').addClass('warning');
    ret_val = false;
}
else
{
    $('#emailerrormessage').addClass('requiredmessage');
}
return ret_val;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for...

```
var isDefault = $(this).val() === $(this).prop('defaultValue');
```

Keep in mind if you are repopulating the `value` attributes after an unsuccessful submission to your server, this will give false positives (depending on your business rules, of course).

Comment: Ah!! thanks for the input Alex.  To be honest, I didn't even know defaultValue existed.  That makes it a lot easier.  I was trying stupid stuff like var default_val = $(this).val(); but I couldn't figure out how to get the value before the value had been input.  thanks again.